# Cancelling mouseover if time not elapsed

Tags: javascript

If someone mouseovers a text box for a second, I want to show a div. But I don't want it to show if they just mouseover quickly as the mouse passes over the text box.

```
<input type="text" value="Fred" onmouseover="overit()">
<div id="dv" style="display:none">Jim</div>

var delay;
function overit()
{
delay = window.setTimeout('showme();', 1000);
}
function showme()
{
document.getElementById('dv').style.display = 'block';
}
```

Unless someone mouseovers the text box for a second, I don't want showme() to be called. How can I cancel showme() being called if the gap between mouseover and mouseout is not at least a second?

Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/S4jx4/

I don't want to use jquery

Comment: use `event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proposed solution almost works. Add an `onmouseout` listener on the input to cancel the timeout.

```
<input type="text" value="Fred" onmouseover="overit()" onmouseout="window.clearTimeout(delay);">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TN952/

Answer (score 0):

You know the function WILL be called after 1 second, so you don't really have to check if the gap is there, you just have to cancel the timeout when mouseleave happens.  If it's already been called, it's been less than a second, and cancelling it doesn't affect anything.

```
var delay;
function overit()
{
    delay = window.setTimeout('showme();', 1000);
}
function showme()
{
    document.getElementById('dv').style.display = 'block';
}
function leaveit() {
    window.clearTimeout(delay);   
}

<input type="text" value="Fred" onmouseenter="overit()" onmouseleave="leaveit()">
<div id="dv" style="display:none">Jim</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hXE28/

Answer (score 0):

remove the inline javascript

```
<input type="text" value="Fred" id="txt" />
<div id="dv" style="display:none">Jim</div>
```

and use event listeners

```
var input = document.getElementById('txt'),
    text  = document.getElementById('dv'),
    timer;

input.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    timer = setTimeout(showme, 1000);
}, false);

input.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
}, false);

function showme() {
    text.style.display = 'block';
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/S4jx4/2/)

Comment: The way you have suggested - you have to mouseover for a second to get the div to appear (which is what I want) but, after the div appears - when you mouseout, the div disappears. Which is not what I want. The other solutions seem to only cancel the mouseover within the first second - which is what I want. You mouseover for a second, the div appears, then you can move your mouse anywhere while you are reading the div.

Comment: @MartinSmellworse - I actually added that "feature" as that's generally what people want, a sort of tooltip thing that appears after a period of hovering, and disappears when the mouse leaves. I've edited the code above to match what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - What did you change?

Comment: I removed the line that reset the display when the mouse leaves.